# If using would implies conditionality are those conditions always unlikely? Because in conditionals when the condition is probable will must be use

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conditionals

I mean yes "would" implies hypothetical situation and conditionality, but didn't we have rule about conditionals that if the condition is probable we must use will and if it's unlikely we will use would. In this sentence "It will be great if you teach me" and It would be great if you teach me" both of these conditions are probable but why does we use will and would on it?

Answer (score 2):

When using "would" to express a remote ("unlikely") conditional, the protasis is usually in the past tense:

> It would be great if you taught me.

This could be used to describe a hypothetical situation.

But often, these past-tense modal auxiliaries are used to make polite requests by suggesting that you aren't *expecting* compliance. In this case, you would usually use such an auxiliary in *both* parts of the conditional. Usually *could* is used, to suggest that you're merely interested in someone's *ability* to do something, rather than asking them to do it directly:

> It would be great if you could teach me.

Comment: Also, "It will be great if you teach me" implies that the hoped-for situation is almost certain to happen.